# Problema con array_rand en PHP

Tags: php, php5, lógica

Hola buenas tardes noches, tengo un pequeño problema con la función array_rand, resulta que estoy obteniendo unos ID desde una base de datos los cuales son 124789 y están siendo almacenados en una lista, cuando se ejecuta la función me trae como resultado números entre 0 y 6, lo cual dentro de lo que quiero hace no tiene sentido porque debería traerme los números mencionados anteriormente, el código que estoy ejecutando es este:

```
$sqlSelectMural = "SELECT * FROM publicacion WHERE estadoPublicacion = 1";

$querySelectMural = mysqli_query($c, $sqlSelectMural);

$idDocumento = array();

while ($resultadoSelectMural = mysqli_fetch_array($querySelectMural)) {

    array_push($idDocumento, $resultadoSelectMural['IDPublicacion']);
    echo $resultadoSelectMural['IDPublicacion'];
};
if (count($idDocumento) >= 6) {

$num1 = array_rand($idDocumento);
$num2 = array_rand($idDocumento);
$num3 = array_rand($idDocumento);
$num4 = array_rand($idDocumento);
$num5 = array_rand($idDocumento);
$num6 = array_rand($idDocumento);

do {
    $num2 = array_rand($idDocumento);
} while ($num2 == $num1);
do {
    $num3 = array_rand($idDocumento);
} while ($num3 == $num1 || $num3 == $num2);
do {
    $num4 = array_rand($idDocumento);
} while ($num4 == $num1 || $num4 == $num2 || $num4 == $num3);
do {
    $num5 = array_rand($idDocumento);
} while ($num5 == $num1 || $num5 == $num2 || $num5 == $num3 || $num5 == $num4);
do {
    $num6 = array_rand($idDocumento);
} while ($num6 == $num1 || $num6 == $num2 || $num6 == $num3 || $num6 == $num4 || $num6 == $num5);
```

Siendo en este caso sql y query los encargados de hacer la consulta a la base de datos, creo una variable que será un array llamada $idDocumento, luego con el while recorro la consulta para ir agregando los datos a la array y una validación if para otra parte del proyecto, luego creo 6 variables distintas que se encargar de recibir 6 números diferentes, 1 cada una y por ultimo 6 do while que se encargan de que nunca los números se repitan en las variables, pero no entiendo porque me genera números del 1 al 5 si debería generarme números random que estén en la array

Comment: Si te lees **bien** la documentación de [array_rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-rand.php) lo entenderás

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te será más práctico hacerlo de este modo:

```php
$sqlSelectMural = "SELECT * FROM publicacion WHERE estadoPublicacion = 1";

$querySelectMural = mysqli_query($c, $sqlSelectMural);

$idDocumento = array();

while ($resultadoSelectMural = mysqli_fetch_array($querySelectMural)) {

    array_push($idDocumento, $resultadoSelectMural['IDPublicacion']);
    echo $resultadoSelectMural['IDPublicacion'];
};
if (count($idDocumento) >= 6) {
  $indices = array_rand($idDocumento,6);
  print_r($indices);
  foreach($indices as $indice) {
    echo $idDocumento[$indice]."\n";
  }
}
```

### Explicación

La función [array_rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-rand.php) devuelve números de índice, no valores, del array pasado como primer parámetro. Y si además le ponemos un segundo parámetro, entonces devuelve la cantidad de índices estipulados en dicho segundo parámetro. En este caso queremos 6.

```
$indices = array_rand($idDocumento,6);
```

Luego, podemos acceder a los valores mediante el nuevo número de índice (del 0 al 5 en este caso porque son 6 elementos) del nuevo array $indices por ejemplo de este modo:  `echo $idDocumento[$indices[2]];` o bien recorremos todos así:

```
foreach($indices as $indice) {
  echo $idDocumento[$indice]."\n";
}
```